# Bounds re Asymptotic Formula for the Sum of Largest Prime Factors

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I have a reference request related to the result :

$\sum_{n=2}^{x} P(n)$ ~ $\frac{\pi^2}{12}\frac{x^{2}}{log(x)}$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$

where $P(n)$ is the largest prime factor of the positive integer $n$.

Theorem 1.1 in [1] below appears to be the first proof of this result, and the result was generalized in Theorem 3.1 in [2] below.

I am looking for upper and lower bounds on the ratio L/R where L and R are the left and right sides respectively of the asymptotic relation above.

Thanks for any help.

References

[1]. K.Alladi and P.Erdos. Pacific J. Math. 71(1977) 275-294

[2]. J.De Konnick and R.Sitaramachandrarao. Indian J. Pure Appl Math. 19(10) 990-1004 Oct 1988

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/181585/bounds-re-asymptotic-formula-for-the-sum-of-largest-prime-factors.